# Python: Finding energy levels and plotting wavefunction of harmonic potential using RungeKutta numerical method

Tags: python, physics, runge-kutta

To make this problem simpler, I have changed the code to plot only 1 graph that plots the wavefunction against the position and also prints the energy level values for a harmonic potential for any n value. I KNOW that the energy levels are correct, BUT the plot is completely wrong as you will see when run, the curve at any n should have a sinusoidal type shape. Lets try fixing this code and the previous code should be easier to run.

```
%matplotlib inline

#importing modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import hermite

m = 9.109383702 * 10**-31 # kg, electron mass
hbar = 1.054571817 * 10**-34 # J.s constant
e = 1.602176634 * 10**-19 ## A⋅s, electron charge
d = 5 * 10**-9 # side length of cubic quantum dot, meters
c = 2.998e8  # speed of light in m/s

xstart = -d/2         # start position,meters
xend = d/2           # end position
N = 2000              # number of points for Runge-Kutta
h = (xend - xstart)/N # size of Runge-Kutta steps
tpoints = np.arange(xstart, xend, h)
ϕ = 1

def V(x, potential_function):
'''
This function returns the potential energy of a particle in a 1D potential well.

Parameters:

x : float
    The position of the particle in meters.
potential_function : callable
    A function that takes the position x as an argument and returns the potential energy at that position.

Returns:

float
    The potential energy of the particle at the given position x.
'''
return potential_function(x)

V0 = 700*e
def H(x):  # define harmonic potential well
    return (V0*(x**2))/((d/2)**2)

def f(r, x, E, potential_function):
    psi = r[0]
    phi = r[1]
    d_psi = phi
    d_phi = ((2*m)/hbar**2)*(V(x, potential_function)-E)*psi
    return np.array([d_psi, d_phi])

def RungeKutta2d(r,x,f,E,potential_function):

    xpoints = [] # initialise empty arrays
    ypoints = []
    for x in tpoints: # loops over all tpoints up to (tend-h)
        xpoints.append(r[0])
        ypoints.append(r[1])
     # Calculate the four Runge-Kutta increments
        k1 = h*f(r,x,E,H)
        k2 = h*f(r+0.5*k1, x+0.5*h, E,H)
        k3 = h*f(r+0.5*k2, x+0.5*h, E,H)
        k4 = h*f(r+k3, x+h, E,H)
        r = r + (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)/6
# these next two lines calculate for the point at t = tend!
    xpoints.append(r[0])
    ypoints.append(r[1])
    return np.array([xpoints, ypoints]) # convert output to numpy array with 2 rows and N+1 columns

n=0
# Define the initial conditions
E_guess = (n + 0.5) * hbar * np.sqrt(2 * V0 / (m * (d/2)**2))
E1 = E_guess - 3e-19
E2 = E_guess

# guess 2 of initial Energy
ϕ = 1


 # Solve for the first guess
 # Here we set the initial conditions in a separate array r
r = np.array([0, ϕ])
soln1 = RungeKutta2d(r,tpoints,f,E1,H)

psi1 = soln1[0,N]            # final element is at index N (counting from zero)

 # solve for the second guess
psi2 = RungeKutta2d(r,tpoints,f,E2,H)[0,N]

 ### now for the secant method to converge on the right answer:

tolerance = e/100000              # set the tolerance for convergence
while abs(E2-E1) > tolerance:
    E3 = E2 - psi2*(E2-E1)/(psi2-psi1)
    # update initial energies for the next iteration
    E1 = E2
    E2 = E3
     # and recalculate wavefunctions
    psi1 = RungeKutta2d(r,tpoints,f,E1,H)[0,N]
    psi2 = RungeKutta2d(r,tpoints,f,E2,H)[0,N]

print("The ground state has a energy of", E3, "J")

# Solve for the ground state wavefunction
soln = RungeKutta2d(r, tpoints, f, E3, H)


psi = soln[0][:len(tpoints)] # we only take the first 2000 points of the wavefunction to mathc the length of tpoints
 # Normalize the wavefunction

I = h*((0.5*psi[0]*(psi[0])) + np.sum(psi[1:-1]*(psi[1:-1])) + 0.5*psi[-1]*(psi[-1]))
psi_norm = psi/np.sqrt(I)

 # Check normalization
norm_integral = h*(0.5*psi_norm[0]**2 + np.sum(psi_norm[1:-1]**2) + 0.5*psi_norm[-1]**2)
print("Normalization integral: ", norm_integral)


plt.axvline(x=-d/2,c='#5f5f5f',ls='-',lw=2.5)
plt.axvline(x=d/2,c='#5f5f5f',ls='-',lw=2.5)
plt.plot(tpoints, psi_norm)
plt.xlabel('Position (m)')
plt.ylabel('Wavefunction')
plt.title('Ground state wavefunction')
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What is "ϕ" in `r = np.array([0, ϕ])`? It seems to be not defined in your code snippet.

Comment: ϕ = np.pi , just an arbitrary phase difference

Answer (score 0):

After reading a bit more about [rk4](https://www.codesansar.com/numerical-methods/runge-kutta-fourth-order-rk4-python-program.htm), I've updated the code.

Now, both `r[0]` and `r[1]` are arrays with len(tpoints) points.

The three energy levels are now separate, but I cannot tell whether this is correct.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

m = 9.109383702 * 10**-31 # kg, electron mass
hbar = 1.054571817 * 10**-34 # J.s constant
e = 1.602176634 * 10**-19 ## A⋅s, electron charge
d = 5 * 10**-9 # side length of cubic quantum dot, meters
c = 2.998e8  # speed of light in m/s

xstart = -d/2         # start position,meters
xend = d/2           # end position
N = 2000              # number of points for Runge-Kutta
h = (xend - xstart)/N # size of Runge-Kutta steps

tpoints = np.arange(xstart, xend, h)

def V(x, potential_function):
    '''
        This function returns the potential energy of a particle in a 1D potential well.

        Parameters:

        x : float
        The position of the particle in meters.
    potential_function : callable
        A function that takes the position x as an argument and returns the potential energy at that position.

    Returns:

    float
        The potential energy of the particle at the given position x.
    '''
    return potential_function(x)

def f(r, x, E, potential_function):
    psi = r[0]
    phi = r[1]
    d_psi = phi
    d_phi = ((2*m)/hbar**2)*(V(x, potential_function)-E)*psi
    return np.array([d_psi, d_phi])

def RungeKutta2d(r, x, f, E, potential_function):
    xpoints = []
    ypoints = []
    for t in tpoints:
        xpoints.append(r[0])
        ypoints.append(r[1])
        k1 = h * f(r, x, E, potential_function)
        k2 = h * f(r + 0.5 * k1, x + 0.5 * h, E,potential_function)
        k3 = h * f(r + 0.5 * k2, x + 0.5 * h, E, potential_function)
        k4 = h * f(r + k3, x + h, E, potential_function)
        r = r + (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) / 6
    xpoints.append(r[0])
    ypoints.append(r[1])
    return np.array([xpoints, ypoints])


V0 = 700*e
def harmonic_potential(x):
    return V0*(x**2)/((d/2)**2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6), gridspec_kw={'wspace':0.3})

# Find energy states for n = 2, 3, 4, 5

ax[0].axvline(x=-d/2,c='#5f5f5f',ls='-',lw=2.5)
ax[0].axvline(x=d/2,c='#5f5f5f',ls='-',lw=2.5)

ax[1].axvline(x=-d/2,c='#5f5f5f',ls='-',lw=2.5)
ax[1].axvline(x=d/2,c='#5f5f5f',ls='-',lw=2.5)

for n in range(1,4):
    # Define initial energy guesses
    E_guess = (np.pi**2 * hbar**2 * n**2) / (2*m*d**2)
    E1 = E_guess - 3 * 10**-21
    E2 = E_guess
# Solve for the first guess
# Here we set the initial conditions in a separate array r

    ϕ = np.pi
    r = np.array([0*np.ones(len(tpoints)), ϕ*np.ones(len(tpoints))])

    psi1 = RungeKutta2d(r, tpoints, f, E1,harmonic_potential)[0, N]
    psi2 = RungeKutta2d(r, tpoints, f, E2,harmonic_potential)[0, N]

### now for the secant method to converge on the right answer:

    tolerance = e/100000              # set the tolerance for convergence
    while np.mean(abs(E2-E1)) > tolerance:
        E3 = E2 - psi2*(E2-E1)/(psi2-psi1)
    # update initial energies for the next iteration
        E1 = E2
        E2 = E3
    # and recalculate wavefunctions
        psi1 = RungeKutta2d(r, tpoints, f, E1,harmonic_potential)[0, N]
        psi2 = RungeKutta2d(r, tpoints, f, E2,harmonic_potential)[0, N]

    soln = RungeKutta2d(r, tpoints, f, E3,harmonic_potential)

    psi = soln[0][:len(tpoints)]

# Normalize wavefunction and plot result
    if n % 2 == 0:
        I = h*(0.5*psi[0]**2 + np.sum(psi[1:-1]**2) + 0.5*psi[-1]**2)
        psi_norm = psi/np.sqrt(I)
        ax[0].plot(tpoints, psi_norm, label=f'n = numerical {n}')
        ax[0].set_xlabel('Position (m)')
        ax[0].set_ylabel('Wavefunction')
        ax[0].set_title("Even wavefunctions")
        ax[0].legend()

    else:
        I = h*(0.5*psi[0]**2 + np.sum(psi[1:-1]**2) + 0.5*psi[-1]**2)
        psi_norm = psi/np.sqrt(I)

        ax[1].plot(tpoints, psi_norm, label=f'n = numerical {n}')
        ax[1].set_xlabel('Position (m)')
        ax[1].set_ylabel('Wavefunction')
        ax[1].set_title("Odd wavefunctions")
        ax[1].legend()

    print(f"Energy level n = {n}: E = {E3}")
```

Results:

```
Energy level n = 1: E = [1.90763525e-18 1.90572128e-18 1.90380733e-18 ... 1.90380733e-18
 1.90572128e-18 1.90763525e-18]
C:\Users\dekarcch\Documents\Python\morsels\stack\distance_map.py:104: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  I = h*(0.5*psi[0]**2 + np.sum(psi[1:-1]**2) + 0.5*psi[-1]**2)
Energy level n = 2: E = [1.68688742e-18 1.68520310e-18 1.68351878e-18 ... 1.68351878e-18
 1.68520310e-18 1.68688742e-18]
Energy level n = 3: E = [1.69884623e-18 1.69716181e-18 1.69547741e-18 ... 1.69547741e-18
 1.69716181e-18 1.69884623e-18]
```

Comment: Hi, after implementing your code, I do get rid of my error, however not matter what energy level I choose, eg n=1,2,3... I keep getting the same energy = 3.3096408782542427e-19. This obviously shouldn't happen, and I have no idea why or how to fix it

Comment: yes, i thought so :) After reading a bit about the rk4 algorithm, I changed the code to deal with the vectorized version. It now gives energy levels for all tpoints. Still looks wrong. Maybe it'lll give you an idea.

Comment: After reviewing my E_guess formula's i found that they were wrong. The correct formulas is: E_guess = (n + 0.5) * hbar * np.sqrt(2 * V0 / (m * (d/2)**2))
E1 = E_guess - 3e-19
E2 = E_guess

However there still must be something wrong with the code because an error when i run your code

Comment: I changed the code above to make it simpler please check

Comment: Also after printing out values for different arrays, I am confident that the problem is to do with the range outta function, the values in the arrays that I gives aren't right